# Await in WebDriverWait selenium

Tags: python, selenium, async-await

I want to use Selenium in my async Programm but It sleeps full 20 seconds in this Code.
This is my Code:

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser,await asyncio.sleep(20)).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'iframeContainerFull')))
```

How can I use WebDriverWait with async and sleep?

Comment: Don't.  No async, no sleep.  The webdriverwait is a polling loop that ignores certain exceptions (such as element not found) for the period of the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of [`WebDriverWait.until()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1104c8f876011fc3fe11eb56d112a10312822866/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L71) can be tweaked to replace `time.sleep()` with `asyncio.sleep()` and avoid blocking:

```
import asyncio
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

driver = ...

end_time = time.monotonic() + 20

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'iframeContainerFull')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    if time.monotonic() > end_time:
        raise TimeoutException()
```